# How to generate a clean patch from Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, diff, patch

The diff command, even using git option, includes path prefixes commonly used on DCS:

```
--- a/file.ext
+++ b/file.ext
```

So applying such patches you should need to using -p1 instead of -p0.

Is there any way to generate clean patched from Mercurial?

Comment: Almost everyone uses -p1 patches. What do you consider the advantage of having a -p0 patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial won't emit -p0 patches.  As @Ringdig points out, they're very seldom what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the see script given in this answer : [transforming patch strip level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007114/transforming-patch-strip-level) to remove the first directory instead of adding it.

Something like this should work (untested) :

```
sed \
    -e 's!^--- a/!--- !' \
    -e 's!^+++ b/!+++ !' \
    < p1.patch \
    > p0.patch
```

Assuming your "p1 patch" is in a file named p1.patch, the output will be in p0.patch